# Find file and send it to ftp

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, find

I am new in bash scripting and I have to write a script that finds the newest .mpg file in directory and then sends it to a ftp server. So far I found command that find my file.

```
#! /bin/bash

find /home/user/directory -type f -mmin -50 -name *.mpg \( ! -regex ".*/\..*" \)
```

This works but I can't figure out how to send the output of that command to ftp server. I've read that I have to use variables, but I can't understand them so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can pipe the output from one command as the input to another with `|`

```
find /home/user/directory -type f -mmin -50 -name *.mpg \( ! -regex ".*/\..*" \) | ftp ...
```

A simpler way to find the latest mpg file:

```
ls -rt /home/user/directory/*.mpg | head -1 | ftp ...
```

If you want to send multiple files [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) will be needed i.e for the 5 newest files

```
ls -rt /home/user/directory/*.mpg | head -5 | xargs ftp ...
```

`ls` lists the files in the `/home/user/directory/*.mpg` where `*` is expanded to any filename where with the `.mpg` extention. `-t` tells `ls` to list in time order and `-r` is reverse sort as we want the newest first not the oldest. The `head` command is used to only show the number of results we want like one `-1` or five `-5`. `head` is usually used for viewing only a certain number of lines in a file, to view the first line in a file we would run `head -1 file.txt`.

Pipe example:

`grep` is used to search for text in files/stdout

So if you wanted to know if `firefox` is contained in the first line of `file.txt` we would `pipe` the output of `head -1 file.txt` to `grep firefox`

`head -1 file.txt | grep firefox`

You can pipe multiple commands together to achieve the result you want.

Comment: I think I have to use find command, because this script will be use within cron job and the newest file will be modified in the last 50 minutes. Please help me with this "pipe to your ftp" command.

Comment: I have found my solution:
FIND COMMAND is:
`find /home/user/path-to-folder/ -type f -mtime -1 -name *.avi \( ! -regex ".*/\..*" \))`

FTP COMMAND is
`lftp -u username,password your.ftp <<EOF
cd /
lcd /home/user/path-to-folder
mirror -R
quit 0
EOF`